# How to move files older than X to another folder?

Tags: files, archive

How do I move files older than 30 days from folder `/storage/current/dbdumps/` to `/storage/archive/dbdumps`?

I tried:

```
find /storage/current/dbdumps/ -type f -mtime +30 -exec mv '{}' /storage/archive/dbdumps \;
```

but seems invalid in Ubuntu 11.04.

Comment: what is the error message?

Answer (score 16):

The command seems ok and in my 11.10 it works. Haven't you missed the trailing slash in the destination folder?

```
find /storage/current/dbdumps/ -type f -mtime +30 -exec mv '{}' /storage/archive/dbdumps/ \;
```

Other thing you may try is using `/bin/mv` insted of just `mv`.

Answer (score 6):

You can try this version (works in 11.10, i guess it will work in other versions too :) ):

```
find /storage/current/dbdumps/ -type f -mtime +30 -print | xargs -I {} mv "{}" /storage/archive/dbdumps
```

Comment: You should use quotation around {} after mv, as files may or may not contain spaces etc.

I would have piped the findings to 
```xargs -I{} mv "{}" /storage/archive/dbdumps/```